# I am unable to use this gTTS module and I can't hear any text in my speakers and it's also showing me adobe reader dialogue

Tags: python, gtts

I have added the image for better understanding:

[image]

## The code

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os

mytext = "Hi, this is an example of converting text to audio. This is a bot speaking here, not a real human!"
audio = gTTS(text=mytext, lang="en", slow=False)

audio.save("example.mp3")
os.system("start hello.mp3")
```

I don't know what to do as I am new to programming and I have used pyttsx3 module and it worked. But I want to be able to use gTTS.

Comment: Try replacing `os.system("start hello.mp3")` with `os.system("start example.mp3")`, you got the file name mixed up.

Comment: Sir, I have changed but I am getting the same error. So I have changed the whole code itself and it worked. Thank you.